# Export-CSV missing quotes on first column

Tags: csv, powershell, export-to-csv

When exporting data to a CSV file, the first column always are without quotes and I do not understand why. I can move and change so that the secound value becomes the first and the same thing happends there since it's the first column.

```
foreach ($item in $item_array)
{
    $global:f_server_s = "SERVER123"
    $global:f_share = "$item"
    $global:f_path = "\\$global:f_server_s\$global:f_share"

    $obj_fileshare_list = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $obj_fileshare_list | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value "$global:f_share"
    $obj_fileshare_list | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Server -Value "$global:f_server"
    $obj_fileshare_list | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Path -Value "$global:f_path"
    $Fileshare_list += $obj_fileshare_list
}
```

CSV output:

```
Name,"Server","Path"
item1,"SERVER123","\\SERVER123\item1"
item2,"SERVER123","\\SERVER123\item2"
```

Save file:

```
$Fileshare_list | Export-Csv ".\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding unicode
```

In this case, why is Name and all the items without double quotes?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Are you opening the file in Excel? Excel's formatting layer will "swallow" the first set of quotes

Comment: Try to remove the `-Encoding unicode`

Comment: I had similar issues with latest PS 5.0 preview. When exported object contained cyrillic characters, `Export-Csv` would output everything in the first line (not header) as `????` (real question marks, not just wrong encoding). I've fixed this by specifying `-Encoding UTF8` parameter.

Comment: I'm using Powershell version 3 I believe.
I've tried to remove "-Encoding unicode", same results.
Yes, i'm using excel. I just tried to open the file in notepad and Powershell Studio, and the format is correct!
@MathiasR.Jessen, feel free to post that and I mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Not able to reproduce on a PS V 5.0 on a french Windows 10. First I would try `-Name Name`. Second a question what is the content of `$item_array` ?

Comment: I maybe a little late, but since i'm encurring in this exact issue right now i can suggest a solution that worked for me. I my case the solution has been to specify the right delimiter (`-Delimiter ";"` )   for my Excel version, which is french. I guess it should work using the parameter `-UseCulture` too.